# how do you set a defaultparametervalue of null for optional parameters?

Tags: c#-4.0, parameters, dbnull

So i have a chunk of code like this:

```
public List<DynamicBusinessObject> GetSearchResultList(Search search, List<CategoryAttribute> listCatAttrib, string sortBy, int startRow, int pageSize, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("")] string state, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("")] string condition, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue("")] string manufacturer)
```

I'd like to know how instead of a default value of "" (empty string) i can instead set it to null? Tried using DBNull.value but it didn't like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the = null

```
public List<DynamicBusinessObject> GetSearchResultList(Search search, List<CategoryAttribute> listCatAttrib, string sortBy, int startRow, int pageSize, string state = null, string condition = null, string manufacturer = null)
```

Comment: No way to do it with DefaultParameterValue?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to simply replace the empty string with null like this:

```
[Optional, DefaultParameterValue(null)] string state
```